# html-requests, skip if TimeoutError when rendering HTML

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, rendering, python-requests-html

I am working on a webscraping script using HTML requests. I scrape the URLs then run through them and commit to a database. I have been able to scrape the links and created a for loop which renders the page then scrape the specific product information. For the majority of links this works but for some, the page will not render and I get a `pyppeteer.errors.TimeoutError`. I am fine with not scraping some links as the majority of the website information is grabbed. I have tried using try and except as below:

```
    session = HTMLSession()
    for link in productlinks2:
        r = session.get(link)
        try:
            r.html.render(sleep=3, timeout=30)
        except TimeoutError:
            pass
```

But this still produces:

```
pyppeteer.errors.TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000 ms exceeded.
```

Is there anyway to skip over the links which won't render in time? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the .get be inside the try?

Answer (score 1):

Do you import your error ?

Then you need to set timeout to your `session.get()` too

Then it depends on your error but, if you have a bad url, you will have an error from the session.get() before rendering the page.
So for example see the different errors that can be caught:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, InvalidSchema, ReadTimeout
from pyppeteer.errors import TimeoutError

session = HTMLSession()

links = [
    'https://www.google.com/',
    'h**ps://www.google.com/',
    'https://deelay.me/4000/https://www.google.com/', # 4s of delay to get the page
    'https://www.baaaadurl.com/', 
    'https://www.youtube.com/', 
    'https://www.google.com/',

]

for url in links:
    try:
        r = session.get(url, timeout=3)
        r.html.render(timeout=1) # timout short to render google but not youtube
        print(r.html.find('title', first=True).text, '\n')
    except InvalidSchema as e:
        # error for 'h**ps://www.google.com/'
        print(f'For the url "{url}" the error is: {e} \n')
        pass
    except ReadTimeout as e:
        # error due to too much delay for 
        # 'https://deelay.me/4000/https://www.google.com/'
        print(f'For the url "{url}" the error is: {e} \n')
        pass
    except ConnectionError as e:
        # error for 'https://www.baaaadurl.com/'
        print(f'For the url "{url}" the error is: {e} \n')
        pass
    except TimeoutError as e:
        # error if timout 
        # in rendering the page 'https://www.youtube.com/'
        print(f'For the url "{url}" the error is: {e} \n')
        pass
```

Print result:

```sh
Google 

For the url "h**ps://www.google.com/" the error is: No connection adapters were found for 'h**ps://www.google.com/' 

For the url "https://deelay.me/4000/https://www.google.com/" the error is: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='deelay.me', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=3) 

For the url "https://www.baaaadurl.com/" the error is: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.baaaadurl.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2596ba6460>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')) 

For the url "https://www.youtube.com/" the error is: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 1000 ms exceeded. 

Google
```

So you can catch errors and continue your loop.